# Alternate for nested Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one button on clicking I need multiple things need to be done, so I went for AJAX and PHP:

```
$('.go_nxt_lsn').live('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var user_id = $('input[name=user_id]').val();
    var course_id = $('input[name=course_id]').val();
    var taskName = "SaveActivity";
    var subTask = "watchvideo";
    var lesson_id = $(this).attr('data-lesson-id');
    var video_id = $(this).attr('data-video-id');
    var course_box = '.course_'+course_id;
    var refresh_boo = 1;

    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>learn/pages/syllabus/saveitems.php',
        datatype    : 'html',
        data        : {subtask:subTask,lessonid:lesson_id,theSubModID:video_id,userid:user_id,prodid:course_id,taskname:taskName},
        success:function(data)
        {
            taskName = "GoToNextLesson"
            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', 
                url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>learn/pages/syllabus/saveitems.php',
                datatype    : 'html',
                data        : {subtask:subTask,lessonid:lesson_id,userid:user_id,prodid:course_id,taskname:taskName},
                success:function(data)
                {   
                    $.ajax({
                        type        : 'POST', 
                        url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>learn/pages/syllabus/learn.php',
                        datatype    : 'json',
                        data        : {user_id:user_id,course_id:course_id},
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            $.ajax({
                                type        : 'POST', 
                                url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>mod/event_calendar/views/default/event_calendar/instantlearn.php',
                                datatype    : 'html',
                                data        : {learn_details:data,refresh_boo:refresh_boo,prodid:course_id},
                                success:function(data)
                                {
                                    $(course_box).replaceWith(data);
                                    $(".accordion").accordion({     
                                        active: false, 
                                        collapsible: true,
                                        heightStyle: "content"
                                   });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am sending four AJAX requests one by one, so I want an alternate for this. This code works fine. But this is so lengthy. Can anybody suggest how I can minimize it?

Comment: This is typical 'tower of doom'. I would consider using promises but first of all you should study your applicaton flow. It looks way too complicated and probably can be simplified.

Comment: @Piotr yes...its actually before flex application. In that application its total 6 steps & somehow i managed to do by this stuff. On single click...so actually i m not sure what i have done its standard or not....so that i posted here for some suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The chain of Ajax calls can be set programmatically, instead of being "hardcoded" as in your code. The next snippet shows a possible approach.

However, as Piotr pointed out, you should study your application a bit more to determine whether that is a good solution.

```javascript
// First generate an array with all the ajax calls than need to be done, in order.
var ajaxCalls = [

    // First ajax
    function(){
        return $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>learn/pages/syllabus/saveitems.php',
            datatype    : 'html',
            data        : {subtask:subTask,lessonid:lesson_id,theSubModID:video_id,userid:user_id,prodid:course_id,taskname:taskName}
        });
    },

    // Second ajax
    function(data){
        return $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>learn/pages/syllabus/saveitems.php',
            datatype    : 'html',
            data        : {subtask:subTask,lessonid:lesson_id,userid:user_id,prodid:course_id,taskname:taskName}
        });
    },

    ...

    // Last function doesn't need to return a promise
    function(data){
        $(course_box).replaceWith(data);
        $(".accordion").accordion({     
            active: false, 
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    }
];

// Every time you run an ajax, you want to set it up so that the next 
// ajax will be called as a response. Let's do a function for that:
function callAjax(var index){

    var thisAjax = ajaxCalls[index];

    // Run the ajax
    var promise = thisAjax();

    // Set up next one if necessary.
    var isLastAjax = (index === (ajaxCalls.length - 1));
    if(!isLastAjax){
        promise.done(function(){
            callAjax(index + 1);
        });
    }
}

// Call the first one
callAjax(0);
```

Comment: What about the declaring the variables ?

Comment: @RIADev What do you mean?

Comment: u didn't declared the parameters...so i asked.

Answer (score 1):

As piotr says, this can be made a lot cleaner by using promises (and a helper function):

```
$('.go_nxt_lsn').live('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var user_id = $('input[name=user_id]').val();
    var course_id = $('input[name=course_id]').val();
    var taskName = "SaveActivity";
    var subTask = "watchvideo";
    var lesson_id = $(this).attr('data-lesson-id');
    var video_id = $(this).attr('data-video-id');
    var course_box = '.course_'+course_id;
    var refresh_boo = 1;

    var toSave = {
        subtask: subTask, 
        lessonid: lesson_id, 
        theSubModID: video_id, 
        userid: user_id, 
        prodid: course_id, 
        taskname: taskName
    };

    callAjax('learn/pages/syllabus/saveitems.php', 'html', toSave)
    .then(function () {
        var nextSave = $.extend({}, toSave, { taskname: "GoToNextLesson" });
        return callAjax('learn/pages/syllabus/saveitems.php', 'html', nextSave);
    })
    .then(function () {
        return callAjax('learn/pages/syllabus/learn.php', 'json', {
            user_id: user_id, 
            course_id: course_id
        });
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        var url = 'mod/event_calendar/views/default/event_calendar/instantlearn.php';
        return callAjax(url, 'html', {
            learn_details:data, 
            refresh_boo:refresh_boo, 
            prodid:course_id
        });
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        $(course_box).replaceWith(data);
        $(".accordion").accordion({     
            active: false, 
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
}

function callAjax(page, dataType, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>learn/pages/syllabus/' + page,
        datatype    : dataType,
        data        : data
    });
}
```